# Wammu - USB Device Name?

Tags: 12.04, usb, filesystem, phone, huawei

I'm trying to get to my phone's filesystem through USB in Wammu, but I'm stuck in the configuration wizard when it asks for a USB device name.  After about an hour of Internet searching, here are the failed solutions I've already tried, starting with the relevant information returned by `lsusb` in terminal.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:101e Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

So I tried opening Wammu through `sudo wammu` in terminal and inputting "/dev/bus/usb/001/003" as the device name, which returns:

```
Error opening device
Device /dev/bus/usb/001/003 does not exist!
```

and then "/dev/bus/usb/001/", which returns:

```
Failed to connect to phone
Description: Error opening device. Unknown, busy, or no permissions.<br>
Function: Init<br>
Error code: 2
```

Another proposed solution was to try "tail -f /var/log/messages" in terminal.  But that only returned a "No such file or directory" message.

Seemingly relevant `dmesg` info:

```
[ 4739.716214] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[ 4739.854137] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4740.854416] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI T Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 4740.867051] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[ 4740.867806] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 4740.870464] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

I don't know why it is coming up as CD-ROM.  But there it is.

If you haven't noticed already, I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to Linux and terminal.  So speaking to me like I'm a three year old is welcome if you can propose a solution.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and the phone is a Huawei U1250.  My computer is an Acer Aspire One D250/KAV60.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE (9/9/2012 17:58)
Tried Bitpim, and it could detect the phone when browsing for a port in the settings, but only shows an empty filesystem.

Also tried gMobileMedia, but it just gets hung up when trying to connect.

Next effort: Use a Windows PC to get the install files from the phone, then run Windows XP in Virtualbox (on this Ubuntu machine) and try from there.

Answer (score 5):

you should try

```
gammu-detect
```

Wammu is command line variant of Gammu,you'd know that.

This will give you a config file gammu you can find the device name in it.

Note the first two devices!

Ex)

```
dave@hnphp006:~$ gammu-detect 
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyACM0
name = Sony_Ericsson Sony_Ericsson_K790
connection = at

[gammu1]
device = /dev/ttyACM1
name = Sony_Ericsson Sony_Ericsson_K790
connection = at

[gammu2]
device = /dev/ttyS0
name = Phone on serial port 0
connection = at

[gammu3]
device = /dev/ttyS1
name = Phone on serial port 1
connection = at
```

... etc..

Answer (score 1):

You will find mounted removable media in /media.  The directory used in /media will usually be the volume name, or the UUID (a long serial number) if there isn't one.  This would be the *filesystem*.

I'm not sure the filesystem is exactly what Wammu wants however.  If it really is looking for the *device name*, and if the device really is being recognised as as a CD-ROM, then the device name should apparently be

```
/dev/sr0
```

To get a list of device names on your system you should use the bash command:

```
blkid
```

Comment: /media is empty with the phone connected.

`blkid` returns only the following known partitions of my computer's internal hard drive:

`/dev/sda1: UUID="91cb3a69-d0aa-472a-8165-b08752c5808b" TYPE="ext4" 

/dev/sda5: UUID="709c2657-d5c2-4e7a-a7b6-f858e5fd391b" TYPE="swap" 

/dev/sda6: UUID="f602dd61-1da8-4612-bd60-5f9e1122a099" TYPE="ext4"`